# Moving an MVC Route to a subpath in the RouteTables.Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am loading MVC views from an embedded resource with a module assembly (identifier by *moduleid*.

What I would like to do is load the appropriate view from the specified assembly, using the *moduleid* as the identifier of the relavent assembly. 
I already have the *virtualpathprovider* and stuff working correctly, what I am having issue is changing the routing paths from the standard pattern, *{controller}/{action}/{id}* to one using the module id such as *{moduleid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}*

Any assistance, idea's or even an answer i know is stupidly simple.

Thanks